# Activity log of database MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database with more than a hundred tables. I am continuously adding columns to existing tables (if required) and I also added few new tables.

Now I want to check what changes I have made in last 3 months. Is there any activity log in MS SQL Server 2012 for that specific database to track changes.

Comment: SQL Source Control?

Comment: @ManOnAMission how?

Comment: This would be better posted on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps this can get you partway. `sys.objects` has create and modify dates but unfortunately `sys.columns` does not. However the latest columns added will have higher column_ids. I don't know that you would be able to pick out deleted columns that easily. Note that changes other than column changes can be reflected by the modify date.

```
select  s.name [schema], o.name [table], o.modify_date [table_modify_date], c.column_id, c.name
from    sys.schemas s
join    sys.objects o on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
left    join sys.columns c on c.object_id = o.object_id
where   o.type = 'U'    --user tables only
and     o.modify_date >= dateadd(M,-3, getdate())
order   by s.name, o.name, column_id;
```

To make this audit easier in the future you can create a DDL trigger that will log all schema changes to a table or in source control if you use something like a SSDT data project to manage your changes.

Answer (score 7):

Right now,your options are limited ,going forward you can try below and also check to see if they help you, now..

1.If you have enabled Audit,you can track the changes

To check ,if you have enabled Audit,You can use below query..

```
select * from sys.dm_server_audit_status
```

If you have not enabled Audit,you can enable it ,following this :[An Introduction to SQL Server  Audit](https://bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/30/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/)..I would not recommend enabling Audit ,unless you need to capture other than what is mentioned in your question

2.Default trace also captures tables created ,but this uses, roll over files mechanism to override last files when the space is full,so you may be out of luck(since you are asking for three months range),but try this:[What event information can I get by default from SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server) to find out to know all the things,which are offered by default trace

I would go with this option and try backing up those files ,depending on when they rollup(since you need only to check table changes)

3.Finally One final option is to query Tlog

```
select * from fn_dblog(null,null) where [transaction name]='CREATE TABLE'
```

the above Tlog option works only if you have Tlog backups for over three months and also you need to restore them

Answer (score 4):

To Check all the activities in past time, you can work with MSSQL Audit. Its the best way to track any changes at any time. Please Check 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx

Comment: how would I know that MSSQL Audit is enabled or not? or this will give me all records without enabling it

Comment: You need to enable Audit so as to record the activities. You can check on object explorer if audit is enabled for not.

Comment: created new Audit under the security in object explorer, and then enabled it. then I created a demo database, table inside it.  right clicked on newly created audit, view logs... but there was nothing just showing one entry AUDIT SESSION CHANGED

Comment: You to to enable audit specification so as to define what component should audit record

Please check :
http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-database-auditing-techniques/

Answer (score 3):

You could run a report from the right click menu on the DB:

[image]

There are several reports that might interest you in this drop down. Or you could possibly create a custom report with just the information that you need.

My Schema report only goes back to 9/3/2016, but I have 1000+ tables with 60+ columns with many updates daily. Yours might go back further.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DDL Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ColumnChanges  
ON DATABASE   
FOR ALTER_TABLE  
AS  
DECLARE @data XML  
SET @data = EVENTDATA()  
INSERT alter_table_log   
   (PostTime, DB_User, Event, TSQL)   
   VALUES   
   (GETDATE(),   
   CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER),   
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),   
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)') ) ;  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any backups going back 3 months, say on tape, you could restore a backup as a different name or to another server and then run a schema comparison via third party tool - Visual Studio, Devart Schema Compare, etc.

Otherwise preemptively setting up the mechanisms before you need them as described by Gameiswar and others is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Take snapshots of the metadata definitions via the "Generate Scripts..." Tasks option from the SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

Store the generated script files in a folder whose name references the current date. Once this has been done more than once, WinDiff can be used to highlight the database changes made between any two snapshots. Choose the "Generate Scripts" options carefully and consistently so that time based comparisons are more beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give the last date of creation and modified of Stored Procedures:

```
select name,create_date,modify_date
from sys.procedures
order by modify_date desc
```